# LINQ Select n list ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this code:

```
foreach(var i in category.count)
{
    var getDifferentSerialNumberforEachLoop = _db.Category.Where(a => a.CategoryID == 
    categoryID).Select(i=>i.SerialNumber).FirstOrDefault();

 //Proceed to do something else with the first serial number value
  .....
 ///end of the first serial number being processed, do again n times (number of categry.count 
 times)
}
```

So you have a case where a CategoryID can have many SerialNumbers associated with it,
Example:

```
CategoryID     SerialNumber
12345          0123445
12345          2345678
12345          0987654
12345          8756478
....           ......(n times)
```

I want to loop through and get each of those serial number and save to the variable, 'getDifferentSerialNumberforEachLoop' process that separately and do it again for all serial numbers associated with that CategoryID. But at the moment I'm only getting the first SerialNumber say 0123445 of course this is because I'm using 'FirstOrDefault()' so even though the Select(i=>i.SerialNumber) value changes each time it loops through category.count the variable, getDifferentSerialNumberforEachLoop will always be the firstordefault value.

My question is: how do I make the `getDifferentSerialNumberforEachLoop` to always have the next `SerialNumber` value?

I can't use `.Take(4)` because I don't know if `category.count` will always be 4 - if that make sense?

Can't use `LastOrDefault` because I wouldn't get the first to the last values, I can't use `List()` because I only want one `SerialNumber` value at a time.

So is there a way I could go about this? I've also seen Takewhile but not sure about that? Any other query I could use for this please? Thank you.

Comment: You could fetch the list of serial numbers (combined with whatever else you're iterating over) and then iterate over the combined list?

Comment: How? doing this, var getDifferentSerialNumberforEachLoop = _db.Category.Where(a => a.CategoryID == categoryID).Select(i=>i.SerialNumber).List();    Will return a list of all SerialNumbers, but I just want one at a time?

Comment: not the best solution but maybe use ToList() and do nested iteration on that list
 var listOfSerialNumbers = _db.Category.Where(a => a.CategoryID ==
             categoryID).Select(i => i.SerialNumber).ToList();
            foreach(var i in listOfSerialNumbers)
            {
                ...
            }

Comment: @Konrad P That makes so much sense - thanks for helping me out! Voted your comment as a thank you gift :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd Suggest something like the below.

```
foreach(var i in category.count)
{
    var getDifferentSerialNumberforEachLoop = _db.Category.Where(a => a.CategoryID == 
    categoryID).Select(i=>i.SerialNumber).ToList().ForEach(serialNo => {
      Console.WriteLine(serialNo);
    });
}
```

You say you "cannot use List because you need one Serial Number at a time" but doing `ToList()` and `ForEach` will allow you to iterate over each Serial Number at a time.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense - thanks for your swift answer! I've given it a positive like as it does what I was stuck on. Thank you!